# Displaying results of multiple tables in same view in mvc with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 tables as follows:
Jobs: IdJob, Description, ...

JobSkill: IdSkill, Id_Job, Title, Description, Level ...

JobRequirments: IdReq, Id_Job, Title, Description ...

(filled with data as follow:
1, Job1, Title1
2, Job2, Title 2
/////
1, 1, Skill1Job1
2, 1, Skill2Job1
3, 2, Skill1Job2
///
1, 1, Req1Job1
2, 1, Req2Job1
3, 2, Req1Job2
4, 2, Req2Job2
/// and so on

In a view I display all jobs from Jobs table as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<JobShop.Jobs>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs Listing Index";
}

<div class="title-lines">
    <h3 class="mt0">Available Jobs Listing</h3>
</div>
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div>
    @{int i = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="bordered @(i++ % 2 == 0 ? "highlighted" : "")">
            <p>@item.IdJob</p>
            <p>@item.Titlu</p>
            <p>@item.DateAdd</p>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="@item.ImageSRC" />
            </div>
            <p class="">@item.Description</p>
            <p class="">@item.Content</p>
            <p class="">@item.Demand</p>
            <p>@item.Address</p> 
            <!--Here I want another div for JobSkills
            <div>
            foreach (var item1 in WhatModel1)
            {
            <div class="JobSkill">
            //Skill(s)
            <p>@item1.Id_Job</p>
            <p>@item1.Title</p>
            <p>@item1.Level</p>
            </div>
            }
            </div>
            -->
            <!--Here I want another div for JobsRequirments
            <div>
            foreach (var item2 in WhatModel2)
            {
            <div class="JobReq">
            //Requirment(s)
            <p>@item2.Id_Job </p>           
            <p>@item2.Requirment</p>
            </div>
            -->
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    }
    </div>
}
else
{<p style="color: red">Sorry ! No record(s) found.</p>}
```

How can I pull data from the other 2 tables on each iteration of main foreach loop?

I also have the model:

```
namespace JobShop
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Jobs
    {
        public Jobs()
        {
            this.JobRequirements = new HashSet<JobRequirements>();
            this.JobSkills = new HashSet<JobSkills>();
        }

        public int IdJob { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdWho { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdd { get; set; }
        public string ImageSRC { get; set; }
        public string Titlu { get; set; }
        public string WhereWhat { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Solicitare { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateStart { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }
        public string Orar { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Latitudine { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Longitudine { get; set; }
        public string ZIP { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<JobRequirements> JobRequirements { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<JobSkills> JobSkills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the relevant part of the controller:

```
namespace JobShop
{
    public class JobsController : Controller
    {
        private JobShopEntities db = new JobShopEntities();

        // GET: Jobs
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            //stuff for paging, searching and sorting
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            //
            var jobs = db.Jobs.Include(j => j.AspNetUsers);
            //Some search stuff
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                jobs = jobs.Where(s => s.Titlu.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Description.Contains(searchString));
            }
            //
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    jobs = jobs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Titlu);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    jobs = jobs.OrderBy(s => s.DateAdd);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    jobs = jobs.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateAdd);
                    break;
                default:
                    //jobs = jobs.OrderBy(s => s.Titlu);
                    jobs = jobs.OrderBy(s => s.DateAdd);
                    break;

            }

            //
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(jobs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            //return View(jobs.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: You can use partialview here.

Comment: You can user `@Html.Action("action", "controller");` helper method, which calls your action method and return your partial view with model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is an instance of `IEnumerable<JobShop.Jobs>`.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
```

Each item is an instance of `JobShop.Jobs`. So you can access the properties of JobShop.Jobs just like you would in any regular C# class.

```
foreach(var jobRequirements in item.JobRequirements)
```

and

```
foreach(var jobSkills in item.JobSkills)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is mainly what I hope to obtain. I only have some issues at nesting level. And also by the model of first iteration I think to display the 2'nd and 3'rd only if I have records in table 2 and/or 3 for given record of table 1. But in this case what model to test for records?

Comment: A foreach loop won't do anything if it's empty. If you don't want to show the other div then you could add an extra check on`item.JobRequirements.Count`.

Comment: Now I'm wonder how can I use the model in more than one view. For example I want to display on home page the latest 5 jobs, but the Job controller have Action Result(index) that returns the Jobs view ?

Comment: It might be better to create a new question for this.